# What would cause this migration to hang?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade an old 1.2.6 Rails application to 2.3.8, and I'm running into a bit of a snag with migrations. Namely, if I have something like ModelName.create(:foo => "bar") in the migration, the migration doesn't complete. It doesn't hit an infinite loop or anything. It just refuses to complete that migration.

Here's some sample code.

This works:

```
class CreateNewsArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :news_articles, :force => true do |t|
      t.string  "name"
      t.string  "image"
      t.text    "body"
      t.boolean "featured", :default => "0"
      t.integer "position"
      t.timestamps
    end
    # Section.create(:name => 'News Articles', :controller => 'news_articles', :description => 'Add, edit, and delete news articles.')
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :news_articles
    Section.find_by_name('News Articles').destroy
  end
end
```

Uncommenting the Section.create(...) means the migration never completes.

Here's the output from rake db:migrate --trace:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateNewsArticles: migrating =============================================
-- create_table(:news_articles, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0531s
```

And after commenting out the Section.create

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateNewsArticles: migrating =============================================
-- create_table(:news_articles, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0479s
==  CreateNewsArticles: migrated (0.0481s) ====================================

** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

I've tried this on another computer, and it works. Same version of rake, same version of ruby, and rails is frozen.

rake --VERSION: `rake, version 0.8.7`, ruby -v: `ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-05 patchlevel 399) [i686-darwin10.3.0]`, rails -v: `Rails 2.3.8`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using ruby 1.8.6-p399 was the culprit. Switching to 1.8.6-p369 solved it.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why this has solved it?  Or where you found that solution!

Answer (score 9):

You can see the same symptom from a different cause: a migration can hang if you are running:

```
$ rails console --sandbox
```

in another process.  Quitting the console process allows the migration to complete.

Comment: This fixed my issue - but mine hung before it got to the line about the time, in contrast to the OP's problem. Once the console had frozen, I couldn't quit the process in the console - Ctrl+C didn't have any effect. Had to close the terminal window to kill the process. Once I'd quit the sandbox console in the other terminal, my db was terminally screwed up - rollback/migrate didn't work, since the original migration had been killed without the ability to gracefully die. I had to rollback to the migration creating the table causing the problem before i could migrate up.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem .. I found out that there was idle transaction which blocked further queries on this table ..

Run:

```
heroku pg:ps
```

To view database processes. You will have to kill idle process:

```
heroku pg:kill 913 --force -a
```

(913 is ID of idle process -> change it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You might also try defining a bar-bones section model in the migration.

Comment: Is the issue that the migration couldn't find the Section model? It seems odd that it would just exit without throwing an error.

Comment: I'm not sure, its just something I try when migrations go weird. Especially helpful if the model has information about an older schema.